# Installing MySQL 5.5 on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: osx, compiling, mysql

I am trying to install MySQL from source on my Mac OS.  I've expanded the source code, and am now trying to configure it.  However, I can't get past that step:

```
My-MacBook-Pro-2:mysql-5.5.13-osx10.6-x86 my$ CC=gcc \
CFLAGS="-O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer" CXX=gcc \
CXXFLAGS="-O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -felide-constructors -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti" \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=complex \
            --enable-thread-safe-client --enable-local-infile \
            --enable-shared --with-plugins=innobase  
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I've run this command successfully on earlier MySQL versions, so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What archive did you download? Is there a file called `configure`? Is it executable?

Comment: mysql-5.5.13-osx10.6-x86.tar.gz

Comment: i do not see a configure executable, no

Comment: Given the name, it's clearly a binary package, not a source package.

Comment: Any specific reason why you aren't using macports or homebrew or a binary download (assuming you downloaded the binary by accident and indeed wanted the source)?

Comment: hmm...homebrew looks interesting...let me give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

Just use [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew). It is by far and away the best package manager for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.5 doesn't use `./configure` anymore. Everything is configured via CMake.